# Why is Bouncy Castle DTLS ReceiveRecord larger than the original buffer

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, dtls

I am currently trying to setup a .NET CoAP DTLS Server. My problem is that bouncy castles DTLS management kept crashing just giving me an "internal error (80)". So I downloaded the library and debugged through it, finally finding where it throws.
Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.DtlsRecordLayer has the receive method for the package:

```
internal int Receive(Span<byte> buffer, int waitMillis, DtlsRecordCallback recordCallback)
        {
            long currentTimeMillis = DateTimeUtilities.CurrentUnixMs();

            Timeout timeout = Timeout.ForWaitMillis(waitMillis, currentTimeMillis);
            byte[] record = null;

            while (waitMillis >= 0)
            {
                ... // wait millis timeout checks

                int receiveLimit = m_transport.GetReceiveLimit();
                if (null == record || record.Length < receiveLimit)
                {
                    record = new byte[receiveLimit];
                }

                int received = ReceiveRecord(record, 0, receiveLimit, waitMillis);

                int processed = ProcessRecord(received, record, buffer, recordCallback);
                if (processed >= 0)
                    return processed;

                currentTimeMillis = DateTimeUtilities.CurrentUnixMs();
                waitMillis = Timeout.GetWaitMillis(timeout, currentTimeMillis);
            }

            return -1;
        }
```

**ProcessRecord** is what actually decrypts the records and writes it into the buffer. Problem is **ReceiveRecord** actually returns a bigger byte value, than the buffer is actually sized.

This is the method

```
        private int ReceiveRecord(byte[] buf, int off, int len, int waitMillis)
        {
            if (m_recordQueue.Available > 0)
                return ReceivePendingRecord(buf, off, len);

            int received = ReceiveDatagram(buf, off, len, waitMillis);
            if (received >= RecordHeaderLength)
            {
                this.m_inConnection = true;

                ... // Epoch checks, to make sure what to read

                int recordHeaderLength = recordEpoch.RecordHeaderLengthRead;
                if (received >= recordHeaderLength)
                {
                    int fragmentLength = TlsUtilities.ReadUint16(buf, off + recordHeaderLength - 2);
                    int recordLength = recordHeaderLength + fragmentLength;
                    if (received > recordLength)
                    {
                        m_recordQueue.AddData(buf, off + recordLength, received - recordLength);
                        received = recordLength;
                    }
                }
            }

            return received;
        }
```

**EDIT**
I first assumed a fragmentation error, but after closer investigation I realized that the **ReceivePendingRecord** function is only triggered on handshake, not on the application data packages afterwards. So I assume the record that triggers the exception isn't actually split into fragments, leaving me with no idea at all.

In wireshark I can see that it always crashes when the package is longer than usual, so maybe the problem is somehow still connected to fragmentation

Comment: The most handshake message are unencrypted, especially the large ones. So wireshark will work. Additionally, if you use a PSK cipher suite, wireshark will also decrypt the messages, if you provide the secret key in the DTLS settings.

Comment: @AchimKraus The crash happens during application data, not the handshake. The handshake itself always goes through. But thank you for the DTLS wireshark settings tip, I was now able to actually read the package and while I do not know why it failed, I at least can see that it is a different package that the others, and a longer one at that.

Comment: If it's an application data record, there is nothing as "fragmentation" inside a DTLS record. Fragmentation is only defined for handshake messages spanning multiple DTLS records. What may happen, if you pass a "large application data block" via DTLS to UDP that it's split on the UDP layer. What does your DTLS record length show in that case? What is the UDP length? (Both are shown in wireshark at each layer.)

Comment: I see, that would explain why the fragmentation methods only triggered for the handshake. My DTLS length is 233 (payload 217 bytes), my UDP length is 254 (payload 246 bytes). My other packages are all below 100 bytes on the DTLS layer

Comment: If you didn't forget a 0 at the end of your numbers, it's hard to see the issue. Are you using a "constraint network"? Pretty low MTU? Did the sizes UDP / DTLS record match? Not that a DTLS record contains a size, which doesn't fit.

Comment: Network isn't constraint in any real form, its a normal LAN connection that gets used to its full extend and the hardware modules have no limit except their 10ms interval. After further analysis I saw that it actually takes the buffer from a previous message and tries to insert this package into it, that's why it results in an overflow. I assume it's not the fault of bouncy castle, but of CoAP.Net another library that I use and that handles some of the DTLS session management. I'll need to investigate further, but for now I thank you for all the help your provided